# What (simple) framework to use for mocking HTTP Backend?

Tags: xml, http, mocking, backend

I have the following issue: We have an SAAS Application that has a HTTP-XML API that we have to test, but our architect is not available anymore.
Now I have to do that work.

The work has two aspects:

1. I have to send POST-Requests to the API - That already works. I use Postman an can trigger operations in the SAAS Application - fine.
2. The Application sends out HTTP-Requests and before we can integrate them in our other systems I have to check the content. What I need is a simple (I am not very  good in doing such things) solution/framework/tool which gives us an endpoint to which we can let the SAAS application send its requests so that I can look at their content.

Can you give me a hint what best to use, when I have to make fast progress? Then I will try to get it wokring with google. At the moment I dont know for what so search. The solution is only for testing and does not have to be sexy.

Thanks everbody

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a simple SpringBoot application to create a RESTful endpoint through which you can check the response of whatever you are sending as part of your HTTP requests.